# Ubuntu 14.04: Lag / Skipping when changing volume

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa, volume-control

Whenever the computer has been under moderate to heavy load, often using Chrome with many tabs and using Youtube, the sound will lag/skip for about 5 seconds whenever I change the volume. The video component of e.g. Youtube lags accordingly.

But the issue is not limited to Youtube, and once the issue has appeared, changing the volume while playing audio in VLC produces the same skipping when the system volume is changed. Changing the internal volume of an application, like Youtbe or VLC, or using the Applications tab in Sound settings does not cause the sound to skip.

My suspicion is that the issue is between ALSA and my sound card. I usually change volume using the multimedia keys, but once the issue appears, using the volume slider or even `alsamixer` or `amixer` produces the same 5 second lag each time the volume is changed.

Rebooting the system resolves the issue, but it's tiresome to have to restart every time I "overuse" the computer and induce the lag.

Here is my output from `lspci -v | grep -A6 Audio`:

```
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 9840
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3801
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 82
    Memory at f0d60000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

--
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3801
    Flags: bus master, slow devsel, latency 32, IRQ 83
    Memory at f0d64000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

I suspect that the offending module is snd_hda_intel. I tried to restarting it, but I simply doesn't seem possible. `sudo alsa force-reload` reports that a number of modules, among them `snd-hda-intel`, are still loaded. This doesn't even disrupt audio being played.

`sudo modprobe -rf snd-hda-intel` doesn't work, giving `modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel is in use.`

Doing `sudo alsactl restore` does disrupt audio, causes the skipping, and resets volume to 100%. But the skipping is still there next time the volume is changed.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue as well. Changing volume, even via the GUI, is laggy and freezes the rest of the UI. Restarting "fixes" the problem until it slowly manifests again.